# Why is my Unity 2.5D textures changing draw order based on camera x position?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, overlap

I have a problem where images change z drawing depending on the xposition of my camera - the image shows the problem - I want it so the positions of the images dont change drawing order to camera

https://ibb.co/syHLY8d

Comment: Do they face the camera?  If so, they should align with the camera's forward direction instead.  http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/CameraFacingBillboard

Comment: They always face forward and never rotate

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue is they're exactly the same depth from the camera, and when the camera moves in the X-coordinate, floating point rounding errors cause the depth values to be slightly different and sort in a different way.

To fix this case you need to move one object slightly further away from the camera, although personally I would say this is generally not an issue worth worrying about, lots of games have small sorting issues like this and most people won't notice.

Comment: One thing I'll add to this is that this issue is specific to a Perspective camera matrix.  If you switch the camera to orthographic rendering, you'll likely lose this visual glitch (although if they're at the exact same Z, you'll probably have z-fighting instead).

Comment: (Empty) It is a perspective camera and I tried moving one of the objects a bit offset on the z plane and still have the problem. And it needs to be fixed ~ Thank you for answering ! :) Still have problem though.